# How to access the other relation in Model.joins(:some_association)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Let's say I have two models, Post and Comment. Post **has_many** Comments.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post
end
```

Suppose I want to get a list of Post, Comment pairs. I could do this:

```
Post.includes(:comments).each do |post|
  post.comments.each do |comment|
    # do something with post and comment
  end
end
```

But let's say that for whatever reason, maybe to do one less database query, I do a join:

```
Post.joins(:comments)
# => [#<Post:0xblahblah>]
```

Given one of the Posts returned by the above query, how do I access the Comment that the Post was joined with?

Answer (score 0):

ps: for eager load, use includes instead of joins. You can access a certain post comments directly, by post.comments; or access a comment post by comment.post